# Чтение файла "как есть"

Tags: perl

Всем доброго времени суток. Хочу написать скрипт (сразу говорю просто так, ради академического интереса) который будет читать файл, различными образами его криптовать и выводить потом отдельный индивидуальный ключ для его расшифровки. Но обрабатывать я хочу любой файл, а не тока текстовый, так что использовать что то вроде ord (x) и chr (x) не хочу, такое уже есть. Насколько мне ведомо, любой файл - это набор из битов. Вот их я и хочу получить. Чтоб можно было потом превратить в нечитаемый любой файл, хоть TXT, хоть JPG, хоть EXE... Вопрос: как прочитать файл именно в том виде каким его воспринимает процессор? Через binmode? У меня что-то не получилось, я для интереса вывел содержимое на экран, но там не было ни единичек ни двоек (пардон - нулей), тока обычная абра-кадабра.... Подскажите, что можно использовать

Comment: Если уж так хочется работать с ноликами: http://www.s3blog.org/bin2dec-i-dec2bin-preobrazovanija.html

Answer (score 1):

Функции pack и unpack - то что мне нужно. Спасибо всем за внимание и беспокойство.